# Can we add a space while using field sets in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, fieldsets

Is there any way to add blank space while using a `Field Set` in `Visualforce Page`.

Comment: **[Vote here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YoQ2AAK)**

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this on several occasions myself. The bottom line is that it's not possible to directly add a blank space to a fieldset.

I have not tried this myself (yet), but there are possible workarounds.

If you know exactly which field(s) you want to insert a blank after, you can use the `rendered` attribute to selectively display another element.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!fromFieldset}" var="field">
    <apex:inputField value="{!someObject[field]}" />
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!field == 'targetField'}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

This could be improved by moving the `field == 'targetField'` into a getter method in your controller (or extension), and by using a custom setting to control which fields have blank elements added after them (or before them, or both).

Comment: Or you could just use the `"required"` attribute to mean render the field itself when true, and a blank space when false. Or vice versa.